# Ĉu estas iu ajn sciencfikcia filmo en kiu troviĝas Esperanto?

Tags: culture

Ne gravas ĉu oni vere parolas la lingvon en tiuj filmoj. Temas pri Esperanto-elementoj en sciencfikciafilmoj.

Mi nur scias pri GATTACA.

Answer (score 5):

> 1980s: The British science fiction comedy Red Dwarf (which first began
>   in 1988), is set on a bilingual spaceship where the signs on the walls
>   are written in both English and Esperanto (for example, the corridor
>   on each level is labelled "Level/Nivelo [###]", and a sign in a movie
>   theatre says "Cinema/Kinejo") – but this only lasted for the first two
>   series, when a redesign of the sets eliminated the Esperanto. Only one
>   episode of the show (Series 2 episode 1, "Kryten") actually features a
>   significant amount of Esperanto being spoken: in which the character
>   of Rimmer is attempting to learn Esperanto from an instructional video
>   and failing miserably (although his underachieving bunkmate Lister can
>   understand it perfectly). In a later episode (Series 5 episode 6,
>   "Back to Reality"), aired in 1992, the crew encounter an "ocean
>   seeding ship" named the SSS Esperanto. Later, when their entire lives
>   are revealed, falsely, to have all been a computer game, the Esperanto
>   translation of Esperanto as "One Who Hopes" is said to have been a
>   clue to use that ship's functioning lasers to defeat the "Despair
>   Squid".
>
> 1985: Night on the Galactic Railroad, a Japanese anime film (based on
>   the novel by Kenji Miyazawa), all the signs are written in Esperanto,
>   to reflect the distinct but unspecific European ambiance of the town
>   and also as a tribute to Miyazawa's interest in the language.
>
> 1994: Street Fighter street signs and labels are in Esperanto; also
>   background speech and even the anthem of Shadaloo, sung in the movie,
>   are in Esperanto.
>
> 1997: Esperanto also makes an appearance in Andrew Niccol's science
>   fiction drama Gattaca, where announcements are read in Esperanto and
>   English.
>
> 2004: The movie Blade: Trinity takes place in a generic city which
>   writer/director David Goyer nevertheless wanted to represent as
>   bilingual (as many cities are worldwide), so the second language
>   spoken in this nameless city, and visible on most of its signage, is
>   Esperanto.
>
> 2010: In the movie Superman/Batman: Apocalypse a mix of esperanto and
>   gibberish is used as the kryptonian language.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Esperanto-language_films#Use_of_Esperanto_in_film_and_television

Answer (score 3):

Nu, la plej fama estas *[Incubus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059311/)* kun William Shatner, sed la kvalito de la Esperanto parolata en ĝi estas tre aĉa, kaj la filmo mem estas stranga kaj ne aparte bona.

Comment: Mi jam spektis Incubus, sed mi dubas ke ĝi estas sciencfikciafilmo?

Comment: Mi samopinias ke ne estas sciencfikcia filmo, sed - la direktoro Leslie Stevens faris sciencfikcion kaj la laboro por restarigi la filmon estis farita de la Sciencfikcia kanalo (the Science Fiction Channel). Ne cxiam por cxiuj estas tute klara, kiam temas pri "speculative fiction" aux sciencfikcio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction#Distinguishing_science_fiction_from_other_speculative_fiction

Answer (score 2):

Vidu [Attack of the Moon Zombies](http://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/attack-of-the-moon-zombies-in-esperanto/). Eble la filmo estas pli horora ol sciencfikcia, sed ĝi ja okazas en la kosmo kaj foje esperantaj skribaĵoj aperas. La DVD havas version profesie dublitan en esperanton.

Answer (score 1):

Pri tio mi povas prognozi la filmon "Trikorpa Problemo (Three Body Problem)" de Liu Cixin, cxina sciencofikcia romanisto. En la unua libro "La pasintaj rakontoj de terglobo" Esperanto estas uzita kiel cxefaj lingvoj en tusxmesagxo al eksterterglobaj kulturoj. Ni atendu! :)

Answer (score 1):

La Laŭzana Esperanto-Societo (Svislando) bondeziras al vi feliĉan novjaron kaj plezuras anonci ke sia freŝdata filmo LA MAGIA LANDO ĉeestas en jutubo. Iru spekti ĝin kaj komentu pri ĝi.

https://youtu.be/AZg-dKW_cbw